# Get object name

Tags: python, object, gtk, pygtk

I've got a GTK window with some widgets on it. There are a bunch of expanders on there, which all have the same `activate` signal handler. In this handler, I'd like to get the name of the widget object.

```
def exItem_activated (self, widget, data=None):
    for i in range (0, 15):
        self.builder.get_object ('exItem' + (str)(i + 1)).set_expanded (False)
    widget.expanded = True

    print widget.name
```

`widget.name` does not work, however; `AttributeError: 'Expander' object has no attribute 'name'`.
So basically, when expander2 is clicked, I want to get "expander2" as a string. When expander14 is clicked, I want to get "expander14" as a string. Is there any way to do this?

If this can't (easily) be done, it would also be an acceptable if I could just get some other property by which I could tell which widget was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding method is called `get_name()` as far as I understand, eg.:

```
print expander.get_name()
```

---

*Edit:* for glade-based UI with gtk 2.20+ the `gtk.Buildable.get_name()` method should be used instead of `gtk.Widget.get_name()` since widget names are stored in `id` attribute of UI definition.

Comment: That seems to output the object **type** rather than the **name**. It outputs *GtkExpander* no matter which button was clicked.

Comment: @RobinJ: and how is this gtk interface constructed? Is it build with glade or manually?

Comment: @RobinJ: try `gtk.Buildable.get_name(expander)` then

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robin/Ubuntu One/Python/gtkreddit/gtkreddit/GtkredditWindow.py", line 65, in exItem_activated
    print gtk.Buildable.get_name(widget)
NameError: global name 'gtk' is not defined`

Comment: `print self.builder.get_name (widget)` works. Please edit your answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @RobinJ: afair, class method should work too if you import gtk module

Comment: @RobinJ: hmm, weird, but may be version-dependent though